# Do you have to close a UDP (dgram) client in Node.js or can you reuse it?

Tags: node.js, udp, datagram

[The docs](http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html#dgram_dgram_send_buf_offset_length_port_address_callback) (and a number of libraries I've looked at) seem to indicate that you close the client every time you send:

```js
var dgram = require('dgram');
var message = new Buffer("Some bytes");
var client = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
client.send(message, 0, message.length, 41234, "localhost", function(err, bytes) {
  client.close();
});
```

I don't really know much about the inner workings of UDP to be honest, but what would stop you from just reusing the `client` each time you want to send a UDP packet? Do you *have* to `close()` it?

I've tested it on `localhost` (that is, reusing the client), and it sends multiple packets fine (at least to the same destination), but that's not really enough of a test to assure me that it would be ok in the big wide world out there.

[The source of send()](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/dgram.js#L160) calls a `_startReceiving()` function, which "binds to a random port", and then "starts receiving" - but I'm unclear as to what should be receiving here, because we're actually sending. In any case, it's enough to make me think that there could be issues with keeping a client around... I'm just not sure what they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse a udp socket for multiple requests. For example this behavior is also seen in multiple tests:
https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/test/simple/test-dgram-pingpong.js

The udp socket binds to a random port, because it has to specify a source address with port.

Comment: Nice find on the test code! So when does it need to be "closed"? Can you keep it open even if you're sending to different host/ports? Could you just have one "client" open for your entire app?

Comment: So far I haven't had to explicitly close a client/socket, and have been able to reuse it fine, so I think this answer is correct

Comment: Hi have you faced the issue with 100% cpu while closing the udp connection when you are using node cluster?  https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7590

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the UDP socket in 3 cases:

1. You are going to create another socket bound to the `same` local port, thus avoiding `port in use` issues.
2. Your peer is using your local port to respond to, and you no longer want those responses.
3. Your peer is using your local port as an identifier, and you no longer want to be associated with it.